# Getting checkbox to display if certain item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

On my *Create.cshtml* page I have a dropdownlist:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.activityID, "Assignment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("activityID", null, "-- Select Activity --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.activityID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And based on the selection of the user, I need a checkbox to appear if a specific item is chosen.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chkbx, "Chk:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chkbx)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chkbx, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I know that this requires JavaScript, but I am unsure of how to write it based on the selection of the dropdownlist.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#chkbox").hide();

    $('#activityID').change(function () {
        var selectedActivity = $(this).val();
        $('#chkbox').hide();
        if (selectedActivity === "Persons") {
            $('#chkbox').show();
        }
    });    
});
```

Razor:

```
<div id="activityID" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.activityID, "Assignment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("activityID", null, "-- Select Activity --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.activityID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



<div id="chkbox" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.chkbx, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.chkbx)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.chkbx, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the `change` event of the dropdown, get the selected value and hide/show the other form control.

The below code assumes you have jQuery loaded in your page.

```
$(function(){
   $("#chkbx").hide();   // hide initially on

   $("#activityID").change(function(){
      var selectedActivity = $(this).val();
      $("#chkbx").hide();
      if(selectedActivity==="SomethingYouExpect")
      {
        $("#chkbx").show();
      }
   });

});
```

Change `SomethingYouExpect` to your specific value you want to check against.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and not getting the result.. the chkbx isn't hiding at all even when the page loads.. I have updated my question with what I have added.. I load jQuery in my `_Layout` view

Comment: Okay so with the JS I added `$(document).ready(function ()` and that hid the checkbox fine.. but I selected 'Persons' in the dropdownlist and it doesn't appear

Comment: That means your if condition is not returning true. put a `alert(selectedActivity)` before the if condition to confirm whether you are getting the correct value.

Comment: Okay I did that. and when I select 'Persons' i get a message from the webpage and it is blank

Comment: Here is a working sample for you to compare against your pages view source http://jsbin.com/qegisezono/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: if my dropdownlist is being created by a table in database that is stuffed in a viewbag `ViewBag.activityID = new SelectList(db.activityTable, "ID", "text", "subcategory", null, null);` would that have something to do with why the alert is saying it's null? or do I need to put the id in the dropdownlist like `@Html.DropDownList("activityID", null, "-- Select Activity --", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "activityID", @class = "form-control" })`, and not in the `<div>`?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct Id in your jQuery selector. this is client side code and has nothing to do with where the data is coming from. I suggest you to use "View source" of your page and get the Id of the dropdown & checkbox and make sure you are using that. Remember that `.val()` method returns the value attribute value of the selected option. not the text.

Comment: figured it out. In the update I gave.. I had the id = "activityID" in the `<div>` so I took that out, and put the id in the dropdownlist like: `@Html.DropDownList("activityID", null, "-- Select Activity --", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "activityID", @class = "form-control" })` and that fixed it.  thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108651/discussion-between-bville-kid-and-shyju).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display property to show/hide the checkbox:

```
document.getElementById("chkbx").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("chkbx").style.display = 'block';
```

Here is an example using a regular list that will display a checkbox if the a particular activity has been selected using the change event:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbox6khc/38/