# Get checkbox to show if certain item under certain subcategory is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I just asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502281/getting-checkbox-to-display-if-certain-item-is-selected).

But now that I use that solution, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of accomplishing this.

My dropdownlist is created by a table in my database.. and let's say my table looks like this:

```
|ID|    |SuperHero|    |Category|
 1       Batman          DC
 2       Superman        DC
 3       Aquaman         DC
 4       Spiderman       Marvel
 5       Ironman         Marvel
 6       Hulk            Marvel
```

with this idea of a table, my dropdownlist looks similar to:

1. DC

   - Batman
   - Superman
   - Aquaman
2. Marvel

   - Spiderman
   - Ironman
   - Hulk

That is created by this:

```
ViewBag.SuperHero = new SelectList(db.superhero, "ID", "SuperHero", "Category", null,null);
```

Now, if you look at the link of the question I asked above.. I have a checkbox that needs to be shown only if certain value(s) are selected in the dropdownlist.

so, with the solution I was given in the other question, I would have to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#chkbox").hide();

    $('#superhero').change(function () {
        var selectedActivity = $(this).val();
        $('#chkbox').hide();
        if (selectedActivity === "1", "2", "3") {
            $('#chkbox').show();
        }
    });    
});
```

So the checkbox will be shown if any superhero from DC is selected.

Can something be done in Javascript to say, if any value under the `Category` *DC*, show the checkbox?  I feel as though this might be more efficient and time-saving rather than me having to manually type in each different value number..

I don't have a problem doing that by any means! I just want to know if there is a more effective way of accomplishing this.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

HTML Generated by `new SelectList()`:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 required" for="superhero">SuperHero</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="superhero" name="superhero"><option value="">-- Select SuperHero --</option>
                <optgroup label="DC">
                    <option value="1">Batman</option>
                    <option value="2">Superman</option>
                    <option value="3">Aquaman</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Marvel">
                    <option value="4">Spiderman</option>
                    <option value="5">Ironman</option>
                    <option value="6">Hulk</option>
                </optgroup>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="superhero" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to show the actual HTML that `new SelectList()` creates. You could just add a class to the options that shows superheroes from DC, and check if the selected option has that class etc.

Comment: @adeneo please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Just check against the selected option's parent's label

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#chkbox").hide();

  $('#superhero').change(function () {
    var selectedOptGroup = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
    $('#chkbox').hide();
    if (selectedOptGroup === "DC") {
      $('#chkbox').show();
    }
  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2 required" for="superhero">SuperHero</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="superhero" name="superhero"><option value="">-- Select SuperHero --</option>
      <optgroup label="DC">
        <option value="1">Batman</option>
        <option value="2">Superman</option>
        <option value="3">The Flash</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Marvel">
        <option value="4">Spiderman</option>
        <option value="5">Ironman</option>
        <option value="6">Hulk</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="superhero" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox">
```

Comment: quick question. if I wanted to say, if `selectedOptGroup` doesn't equal "DC" then Hide the checkbox again?  I added this to what you posted `else if (!selectedActivity === "DC") {
            $('#chkbox').hide();
        }` but if I check something under "DC" and then go back and change it to something under "Marvel" the checkbox is still there

Comment: also, I just chose something under "Marvel" and the checkbox still comes up... and I have what you have as the solution

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid The correct comparison would be `else if (selectedActivity !== "DC")`.  Your line first checks to see if the `selectedActivity` is truthy and then compares.  It reduces down to `else if (false === "DC")` because `!selectedActivity` evaluates to `false` (it'll be a string, provided your markup is accurate).

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid if the provided solution is not working for your application but does work in the test environment, then there is some discrepancy between production and testing.  You should reevaluate your production code and ensure it is comparable to the test code you've provided here.

Comment: I think I found the problem, I added more to `if (selectedOptGroup === "DC", "somethingElse")` instead of `if (selectedOptGroup === "DC" || "somethingElse")`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid That would cause it to do that, yes.  Be aware, however, that your latest condition is still technically incorrect.  It should be `if (selectedOptGroup === "DC" || selectedOptGroup === "somethingElse")`.   Once again, strings are "truethy" in javascript, so the `"somethingElse"` part of your conditional will always evaluate to true.  Because it's a logical OR, that would make the condition fire every time it is evaluated.

Comment: what about `if (selectedOptGroup === ("DC" || "somethingElse"))`? would that be the same as `if (selectedOptGroup === "DC" || selectedOptGroup === "somethingElse")`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid No, it would not.  `("DC" || "somethingElse")` evaluates to `(true || true)`, which evaluates to `true`.  Your statement would them become `if (selectedOptGroup === true)`, which would evaluate to `false`.  The reason for this is because `===` (type-equals) checks both the type and the value of both expressions.  `selectedOptGroup` is a string and `true` is a boolean.  The statement would fail no matter what value `selectedOptGroup` were as long as it remained a string (which it would)

Comment: quick question, where/how did you learn about the part that states `this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid In this context, `this` is an `HTMLSelectElement`.  MDN has a nice [list of it's properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties) which includes the `options` collection and `selectedIndex` property.  `options` returns an [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection), which includes individual [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) elements, which is where I get the `parentNode` bit.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid However, to directly answer your question, from poking around the DOM.  I do a lot of `console.log` and `console.dir` calls to figure out DOM APIs.  You can just study the documentation, but a lot of my personal experience comes from just poking around.